# How to make the message disappear from input box as soon as the user moves the cursor inside the field

Tags: angular

Tool tip message is shown when the user enters wrong confirmation password and moves out of the input field but when the user again moves the focus inside the confirm password input field then the tooltip message remains there. I am trying to make it disappear upon user moving focus / cursor inside that box.

```
<div *ngIf="(registerForm.controls.c_password.touched) && (registerForm.controls.password.value !== registerForm.controls.c_password.value)">
    <div data-tip="Passwords do not match"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="password" name="password" placeholder="Password *" tabindex="5"/>
    <input type="text" formControlName="c_password" name="c_password" placeholder="Confirm Password *" tabindex="6"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML File**

To disappear the tooltip on cursor place in the input field, you need to override focus method and clear the validators like below

```
<input type="text" formControlName="password" name="password" 
   placeholder="Password *" tabindex="5" (focus)="clearValidator()" />
```

**TS File**

```
clearValidator() {
   registerForm.controls.c_password.clearValidators();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are showing tooltip msg div on this condition (registerForm.controls.password.value !== registerForm.controls.c_password.value)
thats why tooltip remains until both values not become same.

on form submit you can check both fields value and set a flag(boolean)

```
  //form.ts
    onFormSubmit() {
    if(registerForm.controls.password.value !== registerForm.controls.c_password.value){
    this.flag = true;
    }
    }

    //form.html

    <div *ngIf="(registerForm.controls.c_password.touched) || (flag)>
        <div data-tip="Passwords do not match"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" formControlName="password" name="password" placeholder="Password *" tabindex="5"/>
        <input type="text" formControlName="c_password" name="c_password" placeholder="Confirm Password *" tabindex="6"/>
    <button type=submit (onclick)="onFormSubmit()"></button>
```